# Dropzone.js get uploaded file image link in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I try to get the dropzone.js full image link right after upload in console(for the beginning) and I can't figure it out how to do this, and I can't find anywhere on the internet. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

For dropzone.js you always need also a server side implementation (http://www.dropzonejs.com/#server-side-implementation). This backend will also provide you the full image link.